# Bestpractices for protecting passwords in python files in views doing email authentication

Tags: django, git, security

I don't want the passwords of my multiple emails to be freely available on github.

I am concerned about multiple views that are sending emails for various purpose. These views are distributed across the project and are openly showing the passwords of our email accounts.

example:

```
def send_enq_mail(user):
    user_email = user.email
    name = user.userprofile
    my_host = 'smtp.zoho.com'
    my_port = 587
    my_username = 'admin@abcd.com'
    my_password = 'Password'
    my_use_tls = True
    connection = get_connection(host=my_host,
                                port=my_port,
                                username=my_username,
                                password=my_password,
                                use_tls=my_use_tls)
    template = ''
    html_content = template.format(name)
    subject, from_email, to = '' 'admin@abcd.com', user_email
    text_content = ''
    connection.open()
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to], connection=connection)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
    connection.close()
```

Now, I already have used a default email in settings.py and that is not tracked by git and the file is not public in github. But i cannot do the same with multiple files that are distributed across the project.

So, what is the best option for me in this case. I mean seasoned developers might be using certain bestpractices. Please share.

Comment: Is this the same email settings as the one you're using in the settings?

Comment: If you have multiple files where you are doing that... Well, repeating code is never a good thing, you could encapsulate that logic in a single file that is included where you need it? Then you can handle it more easily. Also in any case, you should never hardcode a password. Never.

Comment: No, It is one of the multiple functions in files other than settings.py. I mean normal views.py within the project.

Comment: @Renan No, mostly i am not repeating codes. But there are certain places where i have to repeat codes due to import issues and all. Let's say i contain these to one or two files then even i would not be willing to unstage them from git. what can be a solution for that.

Comment: And yes, at many places, i am overriding the email backend in settings.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not store sensitive data under VCS**. This is the best solution. Even if you gitignored the file it can be exposed accidentally, e.g. by a newcomer. And you must realize that any peace of data that was exposed in the Internet remains there. You cannot just [clean up your history](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) and be sure that no one grabbed your passwords.

Personally I like the way [proposed](http://12factor.net/config) by Adam Wiggins in his "12 Factor App". Basically, he says you should store any dynamic configuration, including passwords, on the environment the app is run. This may be either environment variables, that work with any programming language, or app-specific solutions like Java properties (`-Dprop=value`).

Comment: the two awesome links are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you put at least the login credentials, or the entire login logic, in a separate, local file that you then read from/include, and use `git ignore` to prevent said file from being uploaded to GitHub (and modify `.htaccess` to prevent your web-server from serving it). This also lets you more easily update your credentials, if necessary, as you have a single point of reference (that file) for each installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid saving this information in the code change your mail sending function like this:

```
 def send_enq_mail(user, server_info):
      connection = get_connection(host=server_info.host,
                            port=server_info.port,
                            username=server_info.username,
                            password=server_info.password,
                            use_tls=server_info.tls)
```

Now server_infor can be any object that you create dynamically. This approach also helps you improve the *DRYness* of your code. The data can come from configuration files that are not checked into vcs. Alternatively data can come from a database.

```
class ServerInfo(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField()
    post = models.IntegerField()
    ....
```